# Using Mockito and Java 8 streams, how do you ensure a filter clause is working?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, java-stream

Say I've got this code:

```
public void doSomething(Collection<Item> batch)  { 
   batch.stream()      
   .filter(item -> item.group_id == 1)      
   .forEach(this::processItem);
}
```

`processItem()` is private method.

In real life the filter is more complex.  I want to construct a unit test to verify a Collection items that all should fail the filter check, will result in `forEach()` never being invoked.

2 caveats:

- Cannot modify `doSomething()` method signature
- Prefer to keep `processItem()` private void method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make the consumer invoked by `forEach()` a settable field:

```
private Consumer<Item> processingAction = this::processItem;

public void setProcessingAction(Consumer<Item> action) {
   this.processingAction = action;
}

public void doSomething(Collection<Item> batch)  { 
   batch.stream()      
   .filter(item -> item.group_id == 1)      
   .forEach(processingAction);
}
```

Now your test can be:

```
objUnderTest.setProcessingAction( item -> assertThat(item.groupId, is(1)));
objUnderTest.doSomething(listContainingItemsFromOtherGroups);
```

No need for Mockito here - your test-double is a lambda. You can, of course, mock a `Consumer<Item>` if you prefer.

It's a bit of a smell having a method just for testing (`setProcessingAction()`) - but that's because of the hard-coding and tight-coupling you've chosen to do. Why not take the opportunity to make injection (possibly constructor-injection) the primary way of setting the action?

If you're unwilling to make the action injectable, then you're stuck with `processItem()` always being called, and the effects of `processItem()` will be the only way to know what items were filtered.

Comment: This sounds reasonable, test the effects on things I control like mocks used by `processItem()`

Comment: @Ray sorry, I had a brainwave and changed my answer.

Comment: Passing the processor as a dependancy makes sense, I could keep the `doProcessBatch()` signature that way and also keep processor hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

Make the processItem method package-private and check it was never called.

Option 2 (preferred in my opinion):

Switch from forEach to map, and make sure the resulting stream/collection is empty.

Comment: Ideally looking to not change access of processItem.  Cannot alter method signature of `doSomething()`, but that may be only recourse

Answer (score 0):

Thinking out of the box, can you mock something that's called inside processItem and verify that that's not called?

That'd have the same effect as verifying processItem isn't called.